# Link to another HTML file in a same directory

Tags: html, href

I've tried to make a simple menu for my website but it doesn't seem to work. It works perfectly good on my PC but it doesn't work at all on FTP server. Any ideas?

[Here is the web](http://jelraduh.borec.cz/)

Comment: because your hosting add a banner over of links

Comment: ah... How can i fix that

Comment: check my answer

Comment: You are required to post your code here, not your test web site, which has probably already changed and will help no one in the future with same problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because banner over of links

change your css :

```
#menu {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: @RadimJelínek you're welcome, please accept answer by click on tick